# Pagination using IPagedlist not working in added area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagination, routes, pager, pagedlist

I am developing an Asp.net mvc application. In my application I need to implement pagination feature. So I used IPagedList.Mvc. I can implement pagination successfully. But there is a problem with that pagination when it is inside an area. It redirects to the default controller with the same controller name that is currently paginating in an Area.

I have project structure like this

[image]

As you can see there is an area named "Admin". One more thing is there is also same controller name ItemController in default Controllers and in admin area as well. So I seperate them with namespace.

This is my route config in admin area

```
context.MapRoute(
                "Admin_default",
                "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, 
                namespaces: new string[] { "AyarDirectory.Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
            );
```

This is the default route config

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new string[] { "AyarDirectory.Web.Controllers" } 
            );
```

Now I am implementing pagination on ItemController inside admin area. Pagination render successfully.  But the problem is when I click next or another page of pagination, it is redirecting to ItemController in default Contollers folder.

This is how I render pagination in view

```
 @Html.PagedListPager(Model.Items, page => Url.Action("List", new { page }))
```

So I tried to explicitly add area like below

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.Items, page => Url.Action("List", new { page , area = "admin" }))
```

It throws following error

[image]

How can I stop redirecting to different area?

Comment: If `../Admin/Item/List` generated the view, them you should be redirected back to that (and the error is suggesting a duplicate `area="Admin"`). What does `<div>@Url.Action("List", new { page = 1 })</div>` output in the view?

Comment: It outputs this /Admin/Item/List?page=1 . But why my pagination is not working well?

Comment: That's what it should output, and means `@Html.PagedListPager(Model.Items, page => Url.Action("List", new { page }))` is correct. If its not working, it does not seem related to the code you have shown :)

Comment: There are url rewritings in default route. Can it be problem? But I seperated them with namespaces.

Comment: Try removing `namespaces: new string[] { "AyarDirectory.Web.Controllers" }` from the default route config